# Data is not written into /proc file

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I wrote a kernel module which creates a /proc file. I also wrote an user space code which writes into the file and I fetch that written data to my module using "copy_from_user" method and print in the kernel logs.

The data is written successfully on the logs but when I open the proc file in an editor then its blank.

Can anyone explain me why this is so?

The user space code is

```
#include<fcntl.h>

main()
{
    int fd=open("/proc/MY_PROC_FILE", O_RDWR);
    write(fd, "linux is awesome", 16);
    return 0;
}
```

The module is

```
int open_callback(struct inode *p, struct file *q)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "open callback\n");
    return 0;
}

ssize_t write_callback(struct file *p, const char __user *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *s)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "write callback\n");
    char msg[256];
    copy_from_user(msg, buffer, len);
    printk("%s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}

static struct proc_dir_entry *my_proc_entry;

static struct file_operations fs={
    .open=open_callback,
    .read=read_callback,
    .write=write_callback,
    .release=release_callback
};

static int start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "proc module registered\n");
    my_proc_entry=proc_create(file_name, 0, NULL, &fs);
    if(my_proc_entry==NULL)
    {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "os error\n");
            return -ENOMEM;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void stop(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry(file_name, NULL);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "proc module unregistered\n");
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(stop);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You did not implemented `read_callback()`

when you gona read that proc file then that read_callback() will be called. Here you need to write code to write back(Using `copy_to_user()`) what was written earlier in `write_callback()` callback.

First you need to store what was written by user in write_callback() in some global memory for kernel space then on only you can write that back in `read_callback()`

This is best example of what you want to do. http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkmpg/x810

Comment: Sorry for being late....I implemented the read_callback() method but it didnt work....The entire module is here...  http://dpaste.com/1G021KE ...the uspace code is http://dpaste.com/1BY6X0R ... If according to you we have to implement read_callback() method then what about the other proc files?? how are their contents written...Is there any user space system daemon who implements read_callback for those proc files

Comment: @DebeshMohanty Procfs is special file. Here read_callback will be called multiple time so you need to implement such logic that when ever it called first time it will copy buffer to userspace and return size of the buffer and then function should always return zero. See this logic procfs_read() in http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkmpg/x810